# Are random variables independent if their joint density function doesn't impose a constraint?

Tags: probability, parametric, independence

Say I have the following joint density function:

$$f_{X,Y} = \begin{cases} c(x + y^2) & 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

To me it looks like $f_{X,Y}$ is a function of two "independent variables" (in the sense we mean when discussing parametric equations) -- a given value of $x$ does not seem to impose any particular value of $y$ -- does this necessarily always imply $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables (in the sense that $P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For $X$ and $Y$ to be independent, you must have $f(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I agree that is the definition but is it possible that the variables not having a constraint like I described always causes that to be true?

Comment: @JosephGarvin In general, it is possible to have a very complicated expression for $f(x,y)$ that *can* be factorized into $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, but not in an "obvious" way -- so you end up with $X$ and $Y$ being actually independent without "appearing" independent. But to have independence, such a factorization *must* exist for all $x$ and $y$  -- or "almost all": depending on how refined your definition of independence is, a $0$-measure set of "bad" $(x,y)$ pairs may be acceptable.